# Live jQuery datepicker not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

There is a problem with the way I am using the datepicker, it is creating an empty div therefore is not visible when focussing on the text box.

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
     /*url of booking page on site*/
     var url = "aurl";

     /*max number of nights in dropdown*/
     var maxNights = 20;

     /*max number of adults in dropdown*/
     var maxAdults = 10;

     var bookingfeed = new DSMHotels(url, maxNights, maxAdults);
     bookingfeed.create();

     jQuery( "#ArrivalDate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jTyWP/4/

Thanks

Alex

Comment: live? what does that even mean? is there a dead one also?

Comment: it means content that is created by JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `input#ArrivalDate` has the `hasDatepicker` class applied on to it. Remove it and datepicker will work.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/jTyWP/5/)